# Something wrong with active_record

Tags: ruby, database, sinatra

I got this error when i ran the 'rackup' command after using rake for database migrations, i don't understand what this means.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:3:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.6/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from C:/wamp/www/sinatra-template-master/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from C:/wamp/www/sinatra-template-master/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/wamp/www/sinatra-template-master/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
```

pls help, thanks!

i have this in my config.ru file

```
require './app'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'

run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: Without seeing the code of `C:/wamp/www/sinatra-template-master/config.ru` we can’t help.

Comment: Did you accidentally `require` your `Rakefile` or any of your rake task definitions into your `config.ru`?

Comment: oh yeah, i think i might have..

Comment: i have this in my config.ru file.

require './app'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'

run Sinatra::Application

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same config.ru. When i removed

> require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'

Everything started to work.

Method "namespace" is defined in rake/dsl_definition.rb. So, your application extending Sinatra::Base doesn't see it.